# Why is my divider indent different on different devices?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the indent how I like it on iPhone 12 simulator but it's much smaller on my iPhone 8. Why doesn't it match? Is there a way to fix this?

```
Divider(
         color: Colors.white,
         indent: 180,
         endIndent: 180,
       ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [indent](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider/indent.html) property means how much space the divider leaves from its parent's boundaries. So in your example, since iPhone 8 is smaller than iPhone 12 these boundaries change and your divider is shorter. If you want to have the Divider always the same length (in relative terms), you must make the indent and endIndent property relative to the screen size. F.e. by using

```
int _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

then f.e.:

```
 Divider(indent: screenWidth/4, endIndent: _screenWidth/4);
```

If you want the exact same size in cm no matter what screen size, I would just recommend using a container and center it, give it a height of 1 and you desired width.